# How can I stop this recurstion function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
import React, { useCallback, useState } from "react";
import { chat_chat } from "./chat_data.json"; // Length of the chat_chat array is over 10000

function App() {
  const [slug, setSlug] = useState(0);
  // const [stop, setStop] = useState(false);

  // const stopFn = useCallback(() => {
  //   setStop(!stop);
  // }, [stop]);

  const slugAndURLImport = useCallback(() => {
    let i = 0;
    let stop = false;
    const loopFn = () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("stop", i, stop);
        if (chat_chat.length < i || stop) {
          return;
        }
        setSlug(chat_chat[i].slug);
        i++;
        loopFn();
      }, 2000);
    };
    loopFn();
    return () => {
      stop = true;
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <button onClick={slugAndURLImport}> "Start" </button>
      </div>
      <div>{slug}</div>
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            slugAndURLImport()();
          }}>
          Stop
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Is there a way to stop the loopFn that is running?

loopFn is a function that imports data from arrays in json.

Or is there any other way than recursive function?

I want to stop the function when I press the button.

However, a new function starts and stops, and a function that is in progress does not stop.

Is there no way that javascript can stop the function in progress?

I'd like to use it in a react hooks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `setInterval` instead of a `setTimeout` in a recursive function. If you store the output of `setInterval` to a variable (maybe use a `useRef` hook) then you can call `clearInterval` to stop the loop.

Comment: I made a quick [rough example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-avzxuz?file=index.tsx) of how this might work.